# This installation of Xcode 4.3.2 requires Mac OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: xcode, macos

Recently i upgraded to mountain lion.I want to open my old projects in older version of xcode 4.3 and i don't want to use xcode 5 for some reason.
Is there any way to open xcode 4.3 only. I have installation file of xcode 4.3 if its needed to reinstall.

It gives alert "This installation of Xcode 4.3.2 requires Mac OS X 10.7 Lion."

I know how to run my projects in other versions with old simulators... but only need 4.3

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the snarky comments by people like matheszabi; there are good reasons to support the *millions* of units of older devices. Tip: If you are looking at picking up older devices, you'll want to target iOS 4.2.1 not 4.3, as every device supporting 4.3 can be upgraded to iOS 5. See [Highest Version of iOS Supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices#Highest_Version_of_iOS_Supported).

### Virtualizer

To answer your question, "Any suggestions?": **Use a virtualizer** like [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/), [Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/), or [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to run Lion, Mountain Lion, or Mavericks in a virtual environment. This arrangement has many advantages, including resisting the pushing and shoving of Apple to constantly upgrade our OS, Xcode, and iOS targets.

Another advantage is a pristine working environment with its own clean Keychain, Desktop, and so forth having only items related to Xcode project(s). All my own personal stuff is kept to the real Mac. I think of the real Mac like I do my home, with personal property, while I think of the virtual Mac as my office space, my cubicle, having only work-related items.

The one thing you'll need is memory (RAM). If you want a 3 or 4 gig virtual Mac, you'll need about that much space unused on your Mac. By unused, I mean the green colored piece of pie in [Activity Monitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_monitor).

### My Experience

For my current project, I run Xcode 4.6.3 targeting iOS 5 & 6 in Parallels 8 (9 is now available) on a Mac mini (Late 2012) with 16 gigs of memory and i7 quad-core with 8 virtual cores driven by Mountain Lion 10.8.5 on the real Mac, while the virtual Mac has 4 gigs of memory and 2 cores. For the most part this works very well. A few bugs, but no show-stoppers.

The only bad bug is that copying text from the real Mac and pasting into the virtual Mac appends an extra mysterious invisible character that wreaks havoc, including preventing compiling of Objective-C code. I routinely do searches for that evil character, and try to make a habit of hitting Backspace after pasting text brought over from the real Mac.

Another bug: Horizontal scrolling by finger-swiping on my Apple Magic Mouse does not work in the virtual environment.

But Parallels 8 + Mountain Lion + Xcode 4.6.3 works well. You can plug in an iOS device for direct debugging via USB cable – Parallels asks whether you want the connected device to be seen by the real Mac or the virtual Mac.

I've also run earlier versions of Xcode 4 on Lion (besides Mountain Lion) in Parallels 8.

With this arrangement, I am free to consider upgrading my real Mac to Mavericks while keeping my `Parallels 8 + Mountain Lion + Xcode 4.6.3` work environment intact. Though, I may need to shell out some money to upgrade my Parallels 8 to the new version 9. No such thing as a free lunch! (But this arrangement comes close)

### Backups

Tell Time Machine to avoid backing up the 20-50 gig file that is your virtual Mac's hard disk. Instead, do an occasional backup of that large file. More often, make a backup of your import work files and Xcode project, copying off to Dropbox, Google Drive, or external hard drive or SD card. If that file that is your virtual Mac's hard disk ever gets corrupted, you may lose everything. So backup religiously – though I'm sure you do so anyways now. ;-)

Comment: +1 Being an Apple Developer is often like being King Canute in trying to stop the progress of OS version upgrades.  It takes a lot of work to succeed at this.  This answer is very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Xcode 4.3 doesn't know about Mountain Lion, the fix would be downloading and installing Xcode 4.6.2 from [developer center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action), which surely supports it.

Comment: No, in Xcode 4.6 you lose support for iOS 4 in the Simulator.